# Name [java:comp/env/jdbc/WalletDB] is not bound in this Context

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jndi

I know that there is other relative questions but I didn't find a solution in them.
I want to use hibernate with tomcat 8 and jndi for mysql database.
My server context.xml

```
<Context>
    .........
    <Resource auth="Container" 
      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      maxActive="20" 
      maxIdle="10" 
      maxWait="-1" 
      name="jdbc/WalletDB"
      username="root" 
      password="root"
      url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wallet" />   
      .........
 </Context>
```

My applciation web.xml

```
 <resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>java:comp/env/jdbc/WalletDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

My persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="WalletRestPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/WalletDB</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>com.wallet.rest.UserData</class>
    <class>com.wallet.rest.User</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/WalletDB"/>
        <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value ="true"/>

        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
       <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>
           <property name="show_sql">true</property>
          <property name="format_sql">true</property>
           <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</property>
        <property name="connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/WaleltDB</property>
        <!-- Mapping files -->
        <mapping class="com.wallet.rest.User" file="" jar="" package="" resource=""/>
        <mapping class="com.wallet.rest.UserData"/>
      </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

But when I try to load the EntitiManager I get this error:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [java:comp/env/jdbc/WalletDB] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [java:comp].
```

How can I resolve it?